# KeyError: 'name' in python while trying to import csv into dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to load a list into a dictionary from a csv file with python:

content of .csv:

```
"test";"test2"
"row1";"example"
"row2";"example2"
```

my function:

```
def brandnames():
    brands = dict()

    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) #<-- absolute dir the script is in
    rel_path = "imports/manufacturers.csv"
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)

    with open(abs_file_path, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
        for row in reader:
            brands[row['test'].lower()] = row['test']
    return brands
```

This returns the following error:

```
>>> pa.brandnames()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/test/function.py", line 19, in brandnames
    brands[row['test'].lower()] = row['test']
KeyError: 'name'
```

Why is it returning a KeyError?

Comment: One of the cells in the column 'test' has value 'name', and you're trying to access the key 'name' in brands, which apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: Hm... I had the word "name" instead of "test" before. Loaded shell new and now I am getting KeyError: 'test'. I don't get it, the first line is supposed to be my key.
All I want is to pull each line into that dict to have later something like this e.g.: brands['test'][1] with the value "row1"